# jQuery plugin Rangy Inputs make other inputs not work

Tags: jquery

**Solved:**

[Updated version on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sappe/2t99596p/3/)

Thanks to Jainil Nagar for finding the problem.

---

This is really unclear for me.
I'm trying to create a little editor for xml using [rangyinputs jquery plugin](https://github.com/timdown/rangyinputs), but as you can see from this https://jsfiddle.net/sappe/2t99596p/2/ is not possible to write in the other inputs in the page, even if those are not

```
 class="unselectable"
```

I can't understand why. Did I miss something? I put the jquery plugin in the project, the example work fine in it but the other inputs don't work anymore.

---

More information: I didn't set a class unselectable in my css, but in the [demo](https://rawgit.com/timdown/rangyinputs/master/demo/demo.html) is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `e.preventDefault();` for `mousedown` event for every `input`.

```
 $("input").mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // This is what causing the problem

    switch (this.name) {
    }
});
```

You should add default case in the switch case as well.

Comment: Updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/sappe/2t99596p/3/ 
Thank you a lot